# Inserting a Static Block In Category Page - Avoid Cache

Tags: static-block

I want to place a specified Static Block in my category page on my Magento site. The code should look up if a specifically named Static Block exists, and if so display the content of it. I do this on a product page absolutely fine, but it appears that the Block Cache in a category breaks it.

I am using the code

```
 echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId("$categoryBlock")->toHtml();
```

Where `$categoryBlock` is a generated string in the form `category_bluewidget` or `category_redwidget`. In the Static Blocks I have set up separate blocks called `category_bluewidget`, `category_redwidget` etc.

The first page I visit the code works perfectly, however the block appears to be cached and the rest of the pages show the same CMS block on them, not the one that should show.

If I go to admin and turn off `Blocks HTML output` it works fine, I don't want to do that though as it will slow the site down terriibly. I am looking at just stopping this Static Block cache.

Comment: Should have said, I am using `catalog/category/view.phtml` in my custom theme to place the code into

Answer (score 0):

There is one function **getCmsBlockHtml** in **Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View.php**

Kindly override that class using custom module and put below code in that file:

```
 public function getCmsBlockHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getData('cms_block_html')) {
            $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Cms\Block\Block'
            )->setBlockId(
                $this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage()
            )->setCacheLifetime(null)->toHtml();
            $this->setData('cms_block_html', $html);
        }
        return $this->getData('cms_block_html');
    }
```

Hope this helps....!